# PayPal Refund failed

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Please, could you help with the following:

doing the refund from API i'm getting error

> Refund failed: Error: The remote server returned an error: (401)
>   Unauthorized.(22149)

The refund requested for partial amount

I checked token is valid \ transaction data sending is correct \ API setting per sandbox \ currency - all looks ok

Thanks

Comment: is the API caller changing at all between  Capture & Refund

Comment: HI, API caller is the same

Answer (score 0):

Resolution that works for us: the autorizations were created using Website Payments Standard form approach and the capture \ refund were executed using REST API. The refund issue was sorted by swithching to the single recommended approach - REST API integration.